# halve number fields above 10000, dropping decimals

Tags: text-processing, xml, numeric-data

I want to halve the value of the numbers inside the field `PERCENT=""` which are above `10000`. The numbers also can't have decimal places. For example `PERCENT="50001" would need to be PERCENT="25001" or PERCENT="25000"` (used 25001 in my example but doesn't really matter). All the data is also on one line and needs to stay that way. Example below

```
<VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="13" ITEM_ID="0" AMOUNT="6500" GROUPING="0" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="11250" ITEM_ID="31" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="3" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="7000" ITEM_ID="165" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="2" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="47500" ITEM_ID="167" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="2" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="10" ITEM_ID="179" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="0" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="20" ITEM_ID="179" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="0" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="60" ITEM_ID="180" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="0" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="12223" ITEM_ID="180" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="0" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="50001" ITEM_ID="206" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="2" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="2000" ITEM_ID="273" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" />
```

Results should look like

```
<VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="13" ITEM_ID="0" AMOUNT="6500" GROUPING="0" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="5625" ITEM_ID="31" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="3" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="7000" ITEM_ID="165" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="2" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="23750" ITEM_ID="167" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="2" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="10" ITEM_ID="179" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="0" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="20" ITEM_ID="179" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="0" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="60" ITEM_ID="180" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="0" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="6112" ITEM_ID="180" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="0" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="25001" ITEM_ID="206" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="2" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="2000" ITEM_ID="273" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the XML has a proper root tag, using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ xml ed -u '//VALUE/@PERCENT[. > 10000]' -x 'floor(. * .5)'  data.xml
```

The `//VALUE` bit will select any `VALUE` node in the XML. The `/@PERCENT` will select their `PERCENT` attribute. With `[. > 10000]` I restrict the selection to those `PERCENT` attributes whose values exceeds 10000. The *edit* is to apply the function `floor(. * .5)` to the selected values (multiply by 0.5 and round downwards) where `.`, as before, is the placeholder for the value.

This will give you

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="13" ITEM_ID="0" AMOUNT="6500" GROUPING="0" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200"/>
  <VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="5625" ITEM_ID="31" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="3" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200"/>
  <VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="7000" ITEM_ID="165" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="2" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200"/>
  <VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="23750" ITEM_ID="167" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="2" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200"/>
  <VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="10" ITEM_ID="179" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="0" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200"/>
  <VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="20" ITEM_ID="179" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="0" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200"/>
  <VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="60" ITEM_ID="180" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="0" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200"/>
  <VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="6111" ITEM_ID="180" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="0" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200"/>
  <VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="25000" ITEM_ID="206" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="2" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200"/>
  <VALUE MON_ID="10100" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="2000" ITEM_ID="273" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have no restrictions on the implementation then this is pretty easy in perl:

```
perl -p -e 's/PERCENT="(\d{5,})"/sprintf "PERCENT=\"%d\"",int($1\/2)/eg'
```

The `e` added to the `s/../../` pattern tells perl to "execute" the second part as a set of commands rather than doing a simple replacement.

The `g` means "do it for all found strings, not just the first"
So in your original data you had:

```
PERCENT="13"                               
PERCENT="11250"
PERCENT="7000"
PERCENT="47500"
PERCENT="10"
PERCENT="20"
PERCENT="60"
PERCENT="12223"
PERCENT="50001"
PERCENT="2000"
```

In the results we now have:

```
PERCENT="13"
PERCENT="5625"
PERCENT="7000"
PERCENT="23750"
PERCENT="10"
PERCENT="20"
PERCENT="60"
PERCENT="6111"
PERCENT="25000"
PERCENT="2000"
```

(two of the numbers are different to your result because this rounds down; your question says you don't care in that case).

This is a bit of a cheat; a number >= 10000 must be 5 digits or longer, so we search for those and replace the found value with half the original.

Now if we want to make the cut off any arbitrary number, then we can modify it slightly for a stricter test:

```
perl -p -e 's/PERCENT="(\d+)"/$x=$1; $x=int($x\/2) if $x>=10000; "PERCENT=\"$x\""/eg'
```

It's clearer here; the `$x>=10000` test can be changed to whatever you want.

Comment: can also use lookarounds to avoid having to use sprintf.. `perl -p -e 's|PERCENT="\K\d{5,}(?=")|int $&/2|eg'`

Answer (score -2):

Try this in bash:

```
awk '
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        split($i,perc,"\"")
        if ($i ~ "PERCENT" && perc[2] >= 10000)
            printf "%s\"%d\" ", perc[1], perc[2]/2
        else
            printf $i " "
    }
}' $*
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term value.
Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what
limitations and assumptions apply.